# notify-send command issue in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, notifications, ubuntu-16.04, notify-send

I have a text file b.txt with the following text:

> notify-send -i gtk-info "How Are You" -h
>   string:x-canonical-private-synchronous:anything

I have a shell script with the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh

while true;
do if [ -s b.txt ]
then
value="$(cat b.txt)"
exec $value
sleep 0.1
fi
done
```

When I run the script it throws the following error and notification is not displayed:

> Invalid number of options.

But when the text file contains the command with just two words like this:

> notify-send -i gtk-info "Hows You" -h
>   string:x-canonical-private-synchronous:anything

the notification is displayed perfectly.

This issue is happening only when I execute notify-send through a shell script.
How do I display a notification with a message having any number of words?

Comment: You are probably imagining odd things about what `exec` means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `exec $value` with `eval $value`

Comment: While this might perhaps fix the immediate problem, it's generally dubious advice. At the very least, you should have some caveats.

Comment: @tripleee this solution seems to work perfectly without giving any issues

Answer (score 2):

`exec` is entirely the wrong thing to use here. Maybe try

```
#!/bin/sh

while true;
do
  if [ -s ./b.txt ]
  then
    . ./b.txt
    sleep 0.1
  fi
done
```

But running this in a tight loop seems like an odd thing to want to do, and executing a file of unknown provenance is dubious at best. Are you sure this text file will always contain exactly the contents you expect and cannot be modified by anyone? Why is this command being put in a separate file in the first place?

Comment: ./b.txt: Text file busy it gives this error sometimes

Comment: the file is being generated by a docker container. Since docker doesn't support notify-send so I'm using this method to write the command to txt file and execute it on host

Comment: `docker exec whatever | sh` would avoid the temporary file and associated problems. The "text file busy" indicates that Docker hasn't (yet?) closed the file. This still seems like a rather ... peculiar design.